# exclude everything but some subfolders in gitignore not working properly

Tags: git, gitignore

Please help me, it should be some minor thing. I have a subfolder called "assets" in my root. It has many subdirectories and I would like to have only one of them tracked by GIT (this is called "vendor"). The asset folder has a .gitignore file and a test.txt for testing purpose.

The .gitignore file in the asset folder looks like this:

```
*
!.gitignore
!vendor
!test.txt
```

Yet, if I type "git status web/assets/" it only tracks the test.txt and the .gitignore file itself. Why is the vendor folder not tracked? I also tried it with !vendor/

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the vendor folder not tracked?

Because that folder is ignored, with `*` (ignores files and folders).
You can check that with:

```
git check-ignore -v --  web/assets/vendor/aFile
```

You must exclude the `vendor/` folder first, *then* its content:

```
*
!.gitignore
!vendor/
!vendor/**
!test.txt
```

> I want track the vendor folder and all of its already existing subfolders and files

The combination `!vendor/` and `!vendor/**` will allow you to track the vendor folder and all of its already existing subfolders and files.

Comment: I mean I want track the vendor folder and all of its already existing subfolders and files. I checked your tip, but it is still the same. What I dont understand is, that * (or **) in the first row is the general rule to exclude all folders and files. But all those rows with "!" should be exceptions. For the test.txt file it works, but not for the vendor folder. Your script's response is: web/assets/.gitignore:1:**     web/assets/vendor/vendorFile.txt

Comment: @varpet I have edited and fixed the answer (and tested it: it works)

Comment: Thaanks! It solved. Dont understand however why !vendor/ is not enough.

Comment: @varpet Vecause is content would still be ignored by the '`*`' rule which applies to all files and folders.